# Adapt "myRef" from class component into functional component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm working on a single product page where I could manage to show what I want but using class components. To adapt it, I'm having too many problems, especially with myRef.
I am having problems adapting myRef. Could someone help me to know how to adapt it to work with functional components?

this is the code I am working with.

```
class SingleProduct extends React.Component{
  
state = { 
    products: [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "title": "Se perdio Roco",
        "src": [
          "http://flogfotos.miarroba.st/5/0/6/5779506/822.jpg",
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Bianca_8_Meses.jpg",
          "https://sumedico.blob.core.windows.net/images/2020/08/19/perrosboxerblanco.jpg",
          "http://perros.mascotahogar.com/Imagenes/boxer-blanco.jpg"
        ],
        "zone": "Yerba Buena, Tucumán",
        "description": "Perdido desde dia sabado 17 de Junio cerca del Solar del Cerro. Lleva puesto su cadena como se ve en las fotos. Reacciona al llamado de Roco. Es muy cariñoso",
        "condition": "No Encontrado",
        "count": 1
      }
    ],
    index: 0
  };

  myRef = React.createRef();

  handleTab = index =>{
    this.setState({index: index})
    const images = this.myRef.current.children;
    console.log(this.myRef.current.children)
    for(let i=0; i<images.length; i++){
      images[i].className = images[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    images[index].className= "active"
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    const {index} = this.state;
    this.myRef.current.children[index].className = "active";
  }

  render () {
    const {products, index} = this.state;
    return(
      <div className='app'>
        {
          products.map(item =>(
            <div className='details' key={item._id}>
              <div className='big-img'>
                <img src={item.src[index]} alt=""/>
              </div>

            <div className='box'>
              <div className='row'>
                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                <p>{item.zone}</p>
                <span>{item.condition}</span>
              </div>

              <p>{item.description}</p>

              <div className="thumb" ref={this.myRef}>
                {
                  item.src.map((img, index) =>(
                    <img src={img} alt="" key={index}
                    onClick={() => this.handleTab(index)}
                    />
                  ))
                }
              </div>
              <button className='cart '>Ponte en contacto con el dueño</button>

            </div>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have two stateful variables.
To turn it to functional component syntax.

First you need to import all hooks we need from react

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const [products, setProducts] = useState([
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "title": "Se perdio Roco",
    "src": [
      "http://flogfotos.miarroba.st/5/0/6/5779506/822.jpg",
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Bianca_8_Meses.jpg",
      "https://sumedico.blob.core.windows.net/images/2020/08/19/perrosboxerblanco.jpg",
      "http://perros.mascotahogar.com/Imagenes/boxer-blanco.jpg"
    ],
    "zone": "Yerba Buena, Tucumán",
    "description": "Perdido desde dia sabado 17 de Junio cerca del Solar del Cerro. Lleva puesto su cadena como se ve en las fotos. Reacciona al llamado de Roco. Es muy cariñoso",
    "condition": "No Encontrado",
    "count": 1
  }
])
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
```

Template reference in functional syntax with "useRef" hook.

```
const myRef = useRef()
```

"componentDidMount" in the functional component syntax equals "useEffect" hook with empty array dependencies

```
useEffect(() => {
      myRef.current.children[index].className = "active";
}, [])
```

In functional component syntax you don't need the render method to return the JSX code, you just return the JSX you want as you return any value from a method

This is a working example of your component with functional component syntax

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function SingleProduct() {
const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
        _id: "1",
        title: "Se perdio Roco",
        src: [
            "http://flogfotos.miarroba.st/5/0/6/5779506/822.jpg",
            

"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Bianca_8_Meses.jpg",
            "https://sumedico.blob.core.windows.net/images/2020/08/19/perrosboxerblanco.jpg",
            "http://perros.mascotahogar.com/Imagenes/boxer-blanco.jpg",
        ],
        zone: "Yerba Buena, Tucumán",
        description:
            "Perdido desde dia sabado 17 de Junio cerca del Solar del Cerro. Lleva puesto su cadena como se ve en las fotos. Reacciona al llamado de Roco. Es muy cariñoso",
        condition: "No Encontrado",
        count: 1,
    },
]);

const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

const myRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.children[index].className = "active";
}, []);

const handleTab = (index) => {
    setIndex(index);
    const images = myRef.current.children;
    console.log(myRef.current.children);
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].className = images[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    images[index].className = "active";
};

return (
    <div className="app">
        {products.map((item) => (
            <div className="details" key={item._id}>
                <div className="big-img">
                    <img src={item.src[index]} alt="" />
                </div>

                <div className="box">
                    <div className="row">
                        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                        <p>{item.zone}</p>
                        <span>{item.condition}</span>
                    </div>

                    <p>{item.description}</p>

                    <div className="thumb" ref={myRef}>
                        {item.src.map((img, index) => (
                            <img
                                src={img}
                                alt=""
                                key={index}
                                onClick={() => handleTab(index)}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <button className="cart ">
                        Ponte en contacto con el dueño
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

}